# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir desde la tercera hasta la última columna con awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Tengo que filtrar la salida del comando `sar`, mostrando solo de la tercera a la última columna.

La salida del comando es similar a esta:

```
16:20:01        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
16:30:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
16:40:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00    100,00
16:50:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
17:00:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
17:10:02        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
17:20:01        all      0,00      0,02      0,02      0,01      0,00     99,95
17:30:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
17:40:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
17:50:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:00:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:10:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:20:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:30:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:40:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
18:50:01        all      0,01      0,00      0,05      0,01      0,00     99,93
19:00:01        all      0,01      0,00      0,04      0,01      0,00     99,95
19:10:01        all      0,01      0,00      0,02      0,01      0,00     99,96
19:20:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,99
19:30:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00      0,00    100,00
19:40:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,01      0,00      0,00     99,98
19:50:01        all      0,00      0,00      0,02      0,00      0,00     99,98
20:00:01        all      0,01      0,00      0,05      0,01      0,00     99,93
```

La llamada a awk se realizará desde un script en bash.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Por qué debe ser con awk?

Comment: He intentado aplicar la funcion "print" de awk, pero no funciona.

También intenté aplicarlo de esta forma, pero no me detectaba bien el valor de la variable j: http://sprunge.us/VFQh

Comment: Es que la variable no se pasa así. Después de esta pregunta, formula otra con todoceste código. Hay mucjad cosas corregibles y optimizables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es más fácil con `cut`:

```
sar ... | cut -f3-
```

Con esto le estás diciendo que imprima desde el tercero hasta el último campo.

Si el delimitador es un tabulador, deberás indicarlo con `-d$'\t'`.

---

Ejemplos:
Obtiene desde el 3.º y hasta el último campo:

```
$ cut -d$'\t' -f3- fichero
%user   %nice   %system %iowait %steal  %idle
0,00    0,00    0,01    0,00    0,00    99,99
0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00    100,00
0,00    0,00    0,01    0,00    0,00    99,99
```

Obtiene solamente el tercer campo:

```
$ cut -d$'\t' -f3 fichero
%user
0,00
0,00
0,00
```

Comment: gracias!! voy a probarlo

Comment: Al poner el delimitador con `-d'\t'` me sale un error diciendo "el delimitador debe ser un unico caracter"

Comment: @AlmuHS cierto. Edité con la corrección.